# using mode or median

Tags: distributions, inference, median, discrete-data, mode

A survey is conducted among high school students, consisting of 30 questions designed to evaluate their levels of social media addiction. The responses to these questions are aggregated to calculate a final total score, ranging from 0 to 200, where 0 indicates no addiction, and 200 signifies a very high risk of social media addiction. The objective is to analyze and compare the responses of adolescents aged 15-19 with those of young adults aged 19-24, focusing on the risk scores (0-200) across the two age groups.

Here's what my data looks like

```r
# Number of observations
n <- 5000

# Generate skewed distribution
skewed_distribution <- c(
  rbeta(floor(0.8 * n), 2, 5) * 40,  # Beta distribution for 0 to 40
  rexp(floor(0.2 * n), rate = 1/20) + 40  
               # Exponential distribution for 40 to 100
)

# Ensure the length is exactly n
skewed_distribution <- skewed_distribution[1:n]

# Plot the distribution
hist(skewed_distribution, main = "Skewed Distribution", 
     xlab = "Value", col = "lightblue", border = "black")
```

I am uncertain about whether to utilize the median or mode, and I am seeking clarification on the inferences that can be drawn from the mode.

[image]

Comment: Which you should use (if either0 depends on what you are trying to find out. What's your research question? What are these data? You say they are counts, but counts of what? Are you trying to compare counts across groups? Etc.

Comment: @PeterFlom, good suggestions. I have updated my question with more background information.

Comment: Or indeed why not the mean too? The dip around 30 to 40 is interesting and suggestive of two groups of students. To that extent, **any** single summary is of distinctly limited value.

Comment: Will you show some actual data? The current graph shows a mixture of two simple distributions with round parameters; it does not show “what my data looks like”.

Comment: @MattF. Not that I dont want to, but to replicate the actual data is very laborious process. Leaving the actual data aside, what is the most efficient estimator of skewed discrete data like this ? is what I am wondering

Comment: I’m not answering a question about “data like this” when the graph is described misleadingly and is more bimodal than seems sensible to me.

Comment: The fact that you are simulating your data from two separate distributions and combining them together is an indicator that no single measure of central tendency is appropriate here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see any reason to use the mode, based on your amended question.

I'm not sure I would use the median, or, at least, not *only* the median. When a distribution is very skewed and you want to compare two (or more) groups, I think a very good alternative is quantile regression on a variety of quantiles. In particular, you may be interested in the highest quantiles, as these are the kids at greatest risk.

I'd also wonder about the simplicity of the model. If all you have is age, and you only have it categorized like this, well, you can only use the data you've got. But categorizing age is a bad idea. If you have age in years I would use that (and a spline of it). And if you have other data (sex, ethnicity, etc) then it would be good to use those variables as covariates.

Comment: I fully concur with your perspective on applying quantile regression. When generating univariate summaries prior to multivariable analysis, would you consider the median as an informative measure?

Comment: Every measure is a little bit informative, but, here, the median isn't particularly so. I mean, what does it tell you? It's not quite like saying "the median number of legs in humans is 2" but it's in that direction.

Comment: What would be regressed against what, where the objective is to "analyze and compare two age groups"?

Comment: @whuber Score against age (and maybe other things, hard to believe they only have data on age)

Comment: But why use quantile regression when there are just two age groups?

Comment: Because it lets you look at quantiles.  And why not? There's no requirement that there be more than two groups. Also, age shouldn't be grouped and they should add covariates.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the proper measure of central tendency is the median. There are two major reasons for this.

1. because your data is positively skewed, the mean value will be less representative of the typical test score. The reason for this is because the mean represents the arithmetic average of the distribution which is only equal to the expected value when the data set is normally distributed.
2. The mode is not relevant here unless you wanted to identify what the most common test score is. The mode is most commonly used for categorical and ordinal data or for identifying multimodal distribution (mean and median cannot identify multiple peaks). Well, I suppose you could make a solid argument that this is a multimodal distribution due to that low value of the 4th Bin from the left.

To reiterate, the proper measure of central tendency here is median because the data is ratio data and it is heavily skewed. Also, as for mode, you really just need to ask what relevance knowing which score was the most common has. Personally, I do not think that the mode is all that relevant here as the important fact here is that the data is heavily concentrated to the low end of the score range. The mode may tell you which score is most common, but it is possible for the mode to be far away from the bulk of the scores (ex. if you had a class take a test but a third of the class refused to answer any questions, the mode would be zero while most of the scores would likely be above 50 out of 100).

Also, for comparing between two groups using the median as the measure of central tendency, you would use the Mann-Whitney U Test. Quantile regression would be useful only if you were interested in how the age variable impacted the distribution of scores. Now if you wanted to compare the impact of age group on the quantile distribution of the DV, then that would be a case for quantile regression. But that depends entirely on your research question or how detailed you really want to be. If there is something to be gained from the more complex and detailed option of quantile regression, then do it. But personally, I do not see much value in that level of detail (Then again, I can't see the distributions for both age groups and that information could change my position). Regardless, THE ANSWER TO YOUR SPECIFIC QUESTION is that you want to use the median and not the mode. As for whether you should use the Mann-Whitney U Test to compare independent group medians or quantile regression is realistically a judgement call as both have their advantages and disadvantages.

Oh one more thing. Technically the Mann-Witney U Test does not directly compare medians between groups (it compares distributions). It also has its limitations (particularly for data where the distributions are different and heavily skewed). You can also use Mood's Median Test to directly compare the medians between groups. Though the Mood's test can be susceptible to low sensitivity with small sample sizes.
[image]

Comment: I don't know who downvoted my response, but if you're going to do so then you should at least have the decency to explain what I got wrong in my answer. Either you're wrong and it shouldn't be downvoted or I am wrong and I would like to know how I am wrong because, learning.